# How to add two paragraphs in the same line using DocX.dll?

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I would like to know if I can add 2 paragraphs in the same line using docX.dll. For example, I want my document to look like this:

```
MS WORD DOCUMENT:

Name and surname: AAA BBB_________Age:DD

Date of birth: aa.bb.cc.__________Nationality: ABC
```

_ means spacing because I cannot space with spacebar.
The words with a b and c are added words so I would like to make such spacing which would be the same for added words with various lenghts.

Comment: I'm now using simple '\t' which is working but the spacing is not the same for added words with various lenghts. I also googled it but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried to assign a style via `Paragraph.Style` that contains defined tab stops and using \t again. I haven't used docx that often but I remember that word styles are supported.

Comment: I will also try to make 2 paragraphs and set their alignments to left and right and then append one to another. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: might work, but as I said, docX is not my favourite game... sorry

Comment: @PeMaCN Did you get it to work?

Comment: I did this project long ago and if I remember well the best thing you can do is to use table. I'll post example from my code. I used docX.dll. If my answer was helpful please upvote for question and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this proble by using table. This is my code for table:

```
Table t = document.AddTable(2, 4); // rows and columns - 2 and 4
t.Alignment = Alignment.center;
Border b = new Border(Novacode.BorderStyle.Tcbs_none, BorderSize.one, 1, Color.White);
t.SetBorder(TableBorderType.Bottom, b);
t.SetBorder(TableBorderType.Left, b);
t.SetBorder(TableBorderType.Right, b);
t.SetBorder(TableBorderType.Top, b);
t.SetBorder(TableBorderType.InsideH, b);
t.SetBorder(TableBorderType.InsideV, b);
```

Example of adding values to table:

```
t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("AAA BBB:_____________");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide a paragraph mark in order to put two paragraph on the same line, but that's definitely not the best way to go for your requirement.

Assuming I'm following your requirment correctly, then you and Stephen are on the right track using TAB character with TAB Stops defined for the paragraph(s). Tab stops can be defined with left, center or right alignment, so you need a tab stop (probably at the right margin) with right alignment.

You can test this in the Word UI by clicking in a paragraph that needs the spacing. Position your cursor over the button at the left of the ruler (above the "page"). Click on it twice and it will change from left alignment (the default) to center alignment to right alignment. Now position the cursor over the ruler at the place where the text should right align (probably the right margin?). Click once. If there's not yet a TAB character in your text, insert it and you should see the text after the TAB jump to the tab position.

And, as Stephen suggests, "best practise" is to use a style to apply this formatting to paragraphs that should have this "spacing".

An alternative to this approach is to use a two-column table. This has the advantage with longer text that it can break to a new line and still align correctly.